# gcloud functions deploy ignores dot-files

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, gcloud, gcloudignore

My project folder is as follows:

```
.
├── main.py
├── .keys
```

main.py opens and read the content of `.keys`.

I upload this project to GCP Functions as follows:

```
gcloud functions deploy my-function --entry-point func --project my-project --runtime python37 --timeout 30 --trigger-topic my-topic
```

My `.gcloudignore` is the default one:

```
# This file specifies files that are *not* uploaded to Google Cloud
# using gcloud. It follows the same syntax as .gitignore, with the addition of
# "#!include" directives (which insert the entries of the given .gitignore-style
# file at that point).
#
# For more information, run:
#   $ gcloud topic gcloudignore
#
.gcloudignore
# If you would like to upload your .git directory, .gitignore file or files
# from your .gitignore file, remove the corresponding line
# below:
.git
.gitignore

node_modules
#!include:.gitignore
```

When I do this, `.keys` is not uploaded to my GCP function and therefore the code fails to read from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `.keys` is also in your `.gitignore`, `gcloud` will not upload it. You need to remove `#!include:.gitignore` from your `.gcloudignore` or remove `.keys` from your `.gitignore`